# Graphviz, gvpr is not recognized

Tags: svg, graphviz, system-variable, madge

I am trying to use [MaDGe](https://github.com/pahen/madge) to Save dependency graph as a SVG image with CLI command

```
madge --image graph.svg path/src/app.js
```

but I face the error `'gvpr' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

this is where I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` in my PATH.

I also tried adding the PATH in both user and system variables but still the same issue

Answer (score 3):

in windows the executable file is called "dot.exe", I had the same issue as you and fixed it by copying & renaming "dot.exe" to "gvpr.exe" in the /bin/folder

works fine now for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to use madge command by windows command propmt (not git bash or something like that)
it's worked for me